# Elasticsearch java api, hits score always be 1.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I used ElasticSearch java client. I do search with `query_string`, and I get response, but score always be 1.0 .

code is:

```
    String query = "{\"query\": {\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"weblog data4\"}}}";
    SearchRequestBuilder builder = client
            .prepareSearch("flume-2016-08-10")
            .setQuery(query)
            .addHighlightedField("*")
            .setHighlighterRequireFieldMatch(false)
            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true);
    SearchResponse response  = builder.execute().actionGet();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
    System.out.println(response.getHits().getAt(0).getSource());
    System.out.println(response.getHits().getAt(0).getHighlightFields());
    client.close();
```

result is:

[image: score = 1.0]

However, I do search in elaseticsearch-head, I get response with correct score.

[image]

**So, How do I get correct score with java?**

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

change:

> String query = "{\"query\": {\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"weblog data4\"}}}";

to:

> String query = "{\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"weblog data4\"}}";

more details:
[answer by jpountz](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-elasticsearch-java-api-hits-score-always-be-1-0/61565/2)